# iMovie does not see my Mini DV tapes

Tags: macbook-pro, video, imovie, import, firewire

I am trying to import Mini DV on my 2020 MacBook Pro.  My camera is a 22 year old Sony HDR-HC7E. I have a 400 to 800 Firewire cable, and 2 Apple adaptors - Firewire 800 to Thunderbolt 2 and Thunderbolt 2 to 3.    I have tried using iMovie which sees that a camera is plugged in but cannot import the video.  I have also tried LifeFlix and it did not import the video either.  My Sony camcorder is not on the list of camcorders supported by iMovie.  Is there another software I could use to capture my videos?

Comment: Which version of macOS, which version of iMovie are you running?

Comment: It is also possible that you have too many adapter cables. I have seen instances of more than one adapter just not work. Also have you verified that all three cables/adapters work on their own? There could be a defective adapter/cable in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus is that any operating systems after Mojave break compatibility with Mini DV or they're not as reliable as older versions of Mac OS. [LifeFlix](https://www.lifeflix.com/) is in active development, and it even works with the new M1 chip.

Alternatively, if you have access to a Mac with Mojave or earlier, or you can boot the Macbook Pro off a portable SSD running Mojave, you can use Apple's AVCVideoCap: https://www.cuttingcords.com/s/AVCVideoCap.zip

Comment: A 2020 Mac model most likely will not boot with Mojava due to missing hardware drivers.